# Flutter - I can not get Data from own Api, but getting data from public one works

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have multiple problems.
First of all I can't reach the data from my private Api.
When I type the link I get the data, but from the flutter application I get no response. And the fetchData Code should not be the problem, because if I change the link to another public Api I get the data. Any ideas?

Second Problem is that I can not get any connection from my phone to the Internet. It only works when I run my app as an web application. And as you can see in the android file I inserted the internet permission. I also have the android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" line in the manifest file but it seems like a change in there does not make a difference..

fetchData Code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:adupix/models/brand.dart';
import 'package:adupix/net/config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Brand>?> fetchBrands() async {
  print('try start');
  http.Response response = await http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10");
  //final http.Response response = await http.get(kWebUrl+'users/11e23c0b-8e9b-452b-965d-d9b0332462f2');
  print('got data');
  if(response.statusCode == 200){
    print('whaat');
    //final String s = response.body as String;
    // final Map<String, dynamic> brandsData = jsonDecode(s) as Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>;
    // final List<Map<String, dynamic>> brands = brandsData['results'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
    // return brands.map((Map<String, dynamic> json) => Brand.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }else {
    print('ERROR');
  }
}
```

manifest File at android/app/src/main/res/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.adupix">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <application
       android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:label="adupix"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <activity
           android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
<!--    package="com.example.adupix">-->
<!--    &lt;!&ndash; Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application-->
<!--         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.-->
<!--    &ndash;&gt;-->
</manifest>
```

network_security_file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">google.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.google.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://www.google.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">IamOnlyHereToSymbolizeThePrivateApi/</domain>
<!--        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://randomuser.me/api/</domain>-->
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Maybe it's about the API. Did you check the cors policy?

Comment: No I did not check that yet. Where can I find the Cors policy and where do I have to add the necessary Information? The Api runs on the  azure cloud if that helps. Sorry I am totally new to this

Comment: Try sending the requests to your API with Postman and see if you have the response there